# Dominated convergence theorem vs continuity

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2(0,1)$ such that $\lim_n f_n = f$ pointwise and $\vert f_n(x) \vert \leq g(x)$ for some integrable function $g$. By the dominated convergence theorem it follows that
$$
\lim_n \int f_n = \int f.
$$
However, $L^2(0,1)$ is equipped with the inner product
$$
(f,g) = \int f\bar{g}
$$
which in particular is continuous in its first argument (one realizes this since $T_g(f) = (f,g)$ is a bounded linear operator.) Hence for any sequence $f_n$ converging to $f$ (in the $L^2$ norm) we have that
$$
\lim_n T_g(f_n) = T_g(f) \iff \lim_n \int f_n \bar{g} = \int f \bar{g}.
$$
Putting $g \equiv 1$, we get the same conclusion one gets from the dominated convergence theorem, however with weaker assumptions being put on our sequence $\{f_n\}$. Indeed instead of pointwise convergence, we only require convergence in norm; also the requirement of being dominated is dropped completely. So it seems to me that the dominated convergence theorem is of little need in a finite space? Is this reasoning correct or am I mixing some concepts up?

Comment: Convergence in $L^2$ norm is not "weaker than" pointwise convergence. Neither implies the other. (Another reason DCT is still needed in a finite measure space is that integrable functions need not be $L^2$.)

Comment: Oh yes thanks I thought for a second that convergence in norm implies pointwise... So we have (1) pointwise convergence and dominated - free to move limit inside. (2) norm convergence and finite space - free to move limit inside? Im glad to accept your answer if you make one.

Comment: You're starting with the assumption that $\lim_n \int |f_n-f|^2dx =0$. How are you going to prove that in concrete situations? It's definitely easier starting with that as an assumption when proving $\lim_n \int f_n dx =\int f dx$, but there are hidden dragons.